# A CSA group that is not a limit group

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples, finitely-generated

I am looking for an example of a finitely generated torsion-free nonabelian group that is CSA but not a limit group, that is, not residually free. Recall that a group is CSA if all maximal abelian subgroups are malnormal.

The more elementary the example the better.

Comment: limit groups are *fully* residually free, not just residually free.

Comment: Yes but if a CSA group is residually free then it is a limit group.

Comment: The fundamental group of the non-orientable closed surface with $\chi=-1$ is not a limit group (it has a limit group of index $2$, isomorphic to $\pi_1(\Gamma_2)$). It has the presentation
$\langle x,y,z\mid x^2y^2z^2=1\rangle$. Do you know if it's CSA?

Comment: @YCor Its torsion-free hyperbolic, and so CSA.

Comment: Oh, indeed! Hence it's another example, and contrasts with your examples (which probably are not virtually limit groups).

Comment: @YCor That's an interesting question... I don't know if they (hyperbolic one-relator groups) are not virtually limit groups. Certainly either they are definitely not or its unknown (as its unknown whether all hyperbolic one-relator groups are residually finite). I guess if anyone knows then it would be Henry Wilton.

Comment: Ah OK, I would I thought they're known not to be, at least for generic relators. At least the Kazhdan hyperbolic variants (which are not 1-relator) are definitely not virtually limit groups.

Comment: @YCor Probably they're not for generic relators, but I'd have to think. I missed something though: why is $\langle x, y, x\mid x^2y^2z^2=1\rangle$ not a limit group? I had thought it linked to your comment to my question on $\operatorname{Hom}(\Gamma, \mathbb{Z})$, but this group maps onto $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @user1729 I think I read this in the Champetier-Guirardel paper. I think they check by hand that it's not residually free (i.e., that solutions to $x^2y^2z^2=1$ in a free group somewhat degenerate).

Comment: @YCor I just looked at their paper - the relator is basically Lyndon's equation, so any image of this group in a free group must be cyclic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Lemma.** A two-generated limit group is necessarily free or free abelian.

*Proof.* Write $G=\langle a, b\rangle$, and suppose $G$ is neither free nor free abelian. Then $G$ is non-abelian and so the set $\{a,b,[a,b]\}$ contains only non-trivial elements. As $G$ is two-generated and non-free, any non-trivial map to a free group must have cyclic image. Hence, $[a,b]$ is always contained in the kernel of such a map. Therefore, $G$ is not fully residually free, and hence not a limit group. QED

---

Therefore, with only three exceptions ($\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Z}^2$, $F_2$), *any* non-trivial torsion-free two-generated CSA group gives you your example. For example, take $G=\langle a, b\mid abab^2\cdots ab^n\rangle$ for large $n$, which is metric small cancellation, hence hyperbolic, hence CSA, and is torsion-free as the relator is not a proper power (this is a curious, non-trivial fact of both one-relator and small cancellation presentations).

Comment: This is a great answer!  Thanks.

Comment: Also any nontrivial, torsion-free hyperbolic group $\Gamma$ with $\mathrm{Hom}(\Gamma,\mathbf{Z})=\{0\}$ will do the job. There are many such groups.

Comment: This is a good idea too. But can you give me an example of such a group?

Comment: @Isaac every cocompact lattice in $\mathrm{Sp}(n,1)$ for $n\ge 2$ has Property T, hence has no nonzero homomorphism into $\mathbf{Z}$; they are also hyperbolic, and virtually torsion-free (so many are torsion-free).